# Dynamic method dispatch and runtime polymorphism error

Tags: java, methods, polymorphism, run-time-polymorphism

I am trying to understand dynamic method dispatch.

```
class A {
int i=10;
void callme() {
    System.out.println("Inside A's callme method");
} }
class B extends A {
int j=20;
    void callme() {
        System.out.println("Inside B's callme method");
} }
class C extends A {
int k=30;
void callme() {
    System.out.println("Inside C's callme method");
} }
class  Over_riding_loading{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a = new A(); 
        B b = new B(); 
        C c = new C(); 
        A r; 
        B r; //error when i am using this instead of A r;
        C r; //error when i am using this instead of Ar and B r;
        r = a;

        r.callme();
        System.out.println(r.i);//prints 10
        r = b; 
        r.callme(); 
        System.out.println(r.j);//j cannot be resolved or is not a field--what does this mean?
        r = c; 
        r.callme();
        System.out.println(r.k);//k cannot be resolved or is not a field
} }
```

Why are the errors showing? Why can't i create a variable r of type B or C and invoke the callme() method?

edited: To clear up a few things, i am not trying to use the same variable name, i am trying to say that instead of A r; i am trying to  use B r and keep the rest of the code same.

Comment: you cannot have same variable name for different types (in the same scope)

Answer (score 2):

you cannot have same variable name for different types (in the same scope)

modify your main method as

```
   public static void main(String args[]) {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    C c = new C();
    A r;
    //you cannot have same variable name for different types (in same scope)
    //B r; // error
    //C r; // error
    r = a;

    r.callme();
    System.out.println(r.i);// prints 10
    r = b;
    r.callme();

    //here you're getting error because object is available at runtime, what you are getting is a compile time error
    System.out.println(r.j);// can be resolved by casting it as System.out.println(((B)r).j)
    r = c;
    r.callme();
    // here you're getting error because object is available at runtime, what you are getting is a compile time error
    System.out.println(r.k);// can be resolved by casting it as System.out.println(((C)r).k);
}
```

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

At run-time, it depends on the type of the object being referred to (not the type of the reference variable) that determines which version of an overridden method will be executed.

A superclass reference variable can refer to a subclass object. This is also known as upcasting. Java uses this fact to resolve calls to overridden methods at run time.But you can't do vice versa.

Declare `B r1`  and `C r2`  . You are pointing the same variable name for all three classes.

Through  `r= b`  you are referencing an A object to r(As r already references A through `r=a`). So when you call `r.j` it gives error because j is an attribute to B object.

The same explanation for `r.k` case too

Answer (score 0):

> B r; //error
>   C r; //error

The above errors show up because you are trying to use the same variable name `r` with different class types A, B and C. Since A has been used first, it gets registered at the time of compilation and any subsequent attempt to change the type of `variable r` end up in giving compile time error.

> System.out.println(r.j);
>   System.out.println(r.k);

These errors occur at compile time because during compilation the `variable j` and `variable k` are looked for in `class A`. This happens because your `variable r` is of type A. In case, you want to access the `variable j` and `variable k`, please cast `variable r` to `class B` & `class C` respectively.

Hope this helps!

Comment: but i am referring r to the class B and C by giving r=b; and r=c statements. why is not considering that?

Comment: The object assignment i.e. the right hand side will come into picture at runtime. For compilation only the left hand side is considered. Since in LHS, the variable is of type A, hence an explicit cast will be required in order to access variable j and k respectively.

Comment: Does this answer your query?